# Vaadin Charts: Pie chart won't update dynamically

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-charts

I created a Vaadin pie chart with following code.

```
Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.PIE);
DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries("Logins");
chart.getConfiguration().setSeries(dataSeries);
```

I need to update my chart dynamically. I tried following (this code gets executed whenever new data is available).

adding new item:

```
dataSeries.add(new DataSeriesItem("New item", value), true, false);
```

updating existing item:

```
DataSeriesItem dataSeriesItem = dataSeries.get(0);
dataSeriesItem.setY(newValue);
dataSeries.update(dataSeriesItem);
```

But none of the above worked.

The only solution I could find is clearing the chart (`chart.clear()`), re, populating the data series and re drawing the chart (`chart.drawChart()`).

This method is not optimal since it re-draws the chart, and also the selection in the chart gets lost.

Does pie chart support dynamic updating? Can anyone suggest a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `chart.getConfiguration().addSeries(dataSeries)` before updating items. If that doesn't work, I think you should re-draw your chart.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it with `chart.drawChart()` after updating the data series in configurations (`chart.getConfiguration.setSeries(newSeries)`).
In my case (vaadin version 7.6.3), `chart.clear()` was not required.

There are other more complicated ways like vaadin-push plugin as well which I didn't find necessary for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I will share how I solved this problem to Chart Pie in DChart 1.7.0.

```
DataSeries dataSeries = new DataSeries(); 

dataSeries.newSeries();
dataSeries.add( "Food", 500);
dataSeries.add( "Clothes", 1000);

chart.setDataSeries(dataSeries);
chart.show(); //this will update the chart in the browser;
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the question, but I encountered similar problem in 2020, I solved it using below code:

```
dataSeries.clear();
dataSeries.add(new DataSeriesItem("Expense", 120));
dataSeries.add(new DataSeriesItem("Saving", 20));
dataSeries.add(new DataSeriesItem("Balance", 100));
chart.getConfiguration().setSeries(dataSeries);
chart.drawChart();
```